# How to use grid_forget to eliminate a specific ordering of buttons after they have been instantiated

Tags: python-2.7, grid, tkinter

I am building the GUI for a boardgame for my software engineering class.  I am using the TKinter toolkit on Python 2.7 (windows).  I am stuck right now because I cant seem to find a way to ignore/forget a certain ordering of buttons.  Essentially, I am trying to create a grid of buttons that would represent my game board.  And right now, I have a game board that has a total of 49 buttons on a 7x7 grid.

So far this is what I have been able to do:

1. Instantiate all my button objects where columns = x and rows = y.  This easily build a grid of x*y
2. I then place each button into a list (lets call this list1)
3. I want to use my list of button objects to ignore/forget/delete (for lack of a better description) certain buttons.  I am thinking I can create a 2nd list (list2) of the indexes of the button objects that I want to use grid_forget on and then compare my two lists and only keep the ones that are not in list2.  Unfortunately, this doesnt work out the way I want it to.  Here is the code:

   ```
     gameboard = ttk.Labelframe(root, padding = (8,8,8,8), text = "Gameboard", 
                 relief = "sunken")
     #forgetButtons will not be displayed on the game board b/c they do not have a  
     #label (they are not a: room, hallway, starting space)
     forgetButtons = [0,1,3,5,6,7,13,14,16,18,21,30,32,41,42,43,45,46,47,48]
     #this list tracks all the buttons on the gameboard
     myButtons=[]
     count = 0
         for x in range(7): #build a 7x7 grid of buttons (49 buttons total)
             for y in range(7):
                 btn = Button(gameboard, width=7, height=4)
                 myButtons.append(btn)
                 btn.grid(column=x, row=y, padx = 3, pady = 3)

                 #do some comparison here between the two lists 
                 #to weed out the buttons found in forgetButtons

                 #**or maybe it should not be done here?**

                 btn.config(text="Room%d\none\ntwo\nfour\nfive" % x)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `grid_forget` these widgets if you just don't create them.

```
import itertools
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
forgetButtons = [0,1,3,5,6,7,13,14,16,18,21,30,32,41,42,43,45,46,47,48]
myButtons = []

for x, y in itertools.product(range(7), repeat=2):
    if not x*7 + y in forgetButtons:
        btn = tk.Button(root, width=7, height=4, text="Room%d\none\ntwo\nfour\nfive" % x)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, padx=3, pady=3)
        myButtons.append(btn)

root.mainloop()
```

I don't know the order to calculate the position for `forgetButtons` (usually the first index represents the row and the second one the column), but you can easily switch it.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1019227/a-rodas    thanks so much.  That worked great.  I need to study up on the itertools.  Didnt even realize they existed. This is why I love Python.  I just need to have the forgetButtons list re-ordered a bit but I think I can handle that part.